# Trouble creating a web3authModalPack instance

Tags: gnosis-safe

I encountered an error while using the example code from the doc found at this link: https://docs.safe.global/safe-core-aa-sdk/auth-kit/web3auth#create-a-web3authmodalpack-instance

[image]

what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Please create a GitHub issue in the corresponding repository